# How to generate index pages for each group of source code (X number of folders) in doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I want to generate documentation from the C SDK. Let's say three folders (utils, services, drivers) belong to the Libraries group and two folders(main, config) belong to the application group. The document also has an introduction and user guide as separate pages.

So basically Libraries group and application group pages are generated from source code and need to separate as they have in nordic like Libraries and Examples pages.
[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen do you use?. Can you give a small, code, example of what you intent to reach? What did you try so far? Did you have a look at the `GENERATE_TREEVIEW` setting?

Comment: I am using Doxygen 1.8.17 and GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES. So basically the source code generated from five folders comes under a single page in the collapsible form.  I want (utils, services, drivers) folder source code documentation on Libraries page and (main, config) folder source code under Application page so above mention is sample GUI of Nordic where X folder source code comes under Libraries as collapsible page and Examples folder source comes under Examples collapsible page.